# Python XPath and ElementTree doesn't work if first XML parent tag is missing a child tag

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I'm currently using Python to convert a XML file to CSV format by using `ElementTree` library and XPath. My code works will if all of the child tag exists (First name, Last name, and address) for the first parent person tag, but I receive an error message of

> Child Index out of range

when the first person is missing a child tag (only first and last name exist).

What code can I write to bypass this error message? This is my first time using XPath, how can an if statement be added to this? Or should I use something else?

Here's what my XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Members>
    <Person>
      <FirstName>JANE</FirstName>
      <LastName>DOE</LastName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <FirstName>JOHN</FirstName>
      <LastName>DOE</LastName>
      <Address>
        <Address1>123 Straw Street</Address1>
        <Address2></Address2>
        <City>Apple</City>
        <State>Test</State>
        <ZipCode>123456    </ZipCode>
      </Address>
    </Person>
</Members>
```

Current Python Code:

```
import  csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("TestStack.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

xml_data_to_csv =open('OutputStack.csv','w')

Csv_writer=csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv)
list_head=[]

count=0
for element in root.findall('Person'):
    person = []

    #Get head by tag
    if count == 0:
       FirstName = element.find('FirstName').tag
       list_head.append(FirstName)

       LastName = element.find('LastName').tag
       list_head.append(LastName)

       Address = element[2].tag
       list_head.append(Address)

       Csv_writer.writerow(list_head)
       count = count +1

    #get child node
    FirstName = element.find('FirstName').text
    person.append(FirstName)

    LastName = element.find('LastName').text
    person.append(LastName)

    person.append([e.text for e in element.findall('Address//')])

    #Write List_nodes to csv
    Csv_writer.writerow(person)
xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

Comment: It can be done with lxml, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the header should be predefined. I doubt that your CSV import backend accepts any format.

```
import  csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("in.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

xml_data_to_csv =open('out.csv','w')

Csv_writer=csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv)
list_head=['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Address']
Csv_writer.writerow(list_head)

for element in root.findall('Person'):
    person = []

    #get child node
    FirstName = element.find('FirstName').text
    person.append(FirstName)

    LastName = element.find('LastName').text
    person.append(LastName)

    person.append([e.text for e in element.findall('Address//')])

    #Write List_nodes to csv
    Csv_writer.writerow(person)
xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

Otherwise, you could either handle the exception or check how many elements exist like this

```
if len(element) > 2:
    head_list.append(element[2])
    continue
```

Preinitialize the `head_list = [None] * 3 #len(element)`, and collect the headers (as the show-up) and persons during the for-loop, then write everything at the end. I would not recommend that route.

Comment: Thanks wp78de, you're a genius! That worked perfectly!

Comment: how did you know that tags in the head_list would work?

Comment: @Codr4Life I just figured how I would code this any language - sometimes Python is too slick.